# JS button only firing on first element

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button that changes text upon clicking. However, the action only works for the first button on the page. Any button further down in the code, that has the same action, doesn't work. How do I change the JS so that it allows for multiple firings of the event?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="addtocart">
   <a href="#" class="add-to-cart">
      <div class="pretext">
      ADD TO CART
      </div>
   </a>
   <div class="pretext done">
      <div class="posttext"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> ADDED</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
const button = document.querySelector(".addtocart");
const done = document.querySelector(".done");
console.log(button);
let added = false;
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (added) {
    done.style.transform = "translate(-110%) skew(-40deg)";
    added = false;
  } else {
    done.style.transform = "translate(0px)";
    added = true;
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to [select all button elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Using querySelectorAll.

This will return an array of DOM elements matching the query. Then you loop through and add the event listener to each.

What the above code does is, select the first instance of a DOM element with `.addtocart`, not every instance, then adds the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CYGGD/641/#fork) is example of working code. You need to use this keyword to get what you want.

```
<div class="addtocart">
   <a href="#" class="add-to-cart" id="addToCardItem1"  onclick="addToCart(this)">
      <div class="pretext">
      ADD TO CART
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="addtocart"  id="addToCardItem1" onclick="addToCart(this)">
   <a href="#" class="add-to-cart">
      <div class="pretext">
      ADD TO CART
      </div>
   </a>
</div>


<script>
function addToCart(elem) {
    alert(elem.id);
}
</script>
```